# using client Credentials from registered Azure ADD app to access Azure Data Catalog API

Tags: .net, azure-active-directory, azure-data-catalog

I'm trying to retrieve data from the Azure Data Catalogue using a registered app clientCredentials. I can get a bearer token fine but when i'm trying to use the token with the Azure Data Catalogue API I get -

```
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="svc", error="InsufficientScope", error_description="A token with user_impersonation scope is required.", scope="user_impersonation"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

I've given the app permissions against AD and ADC, and also added a contributor role to the app within AD.

Not sure why this is happening... driving me nuts.

I can get this working using userpassword credentials in a console app but this falls apart when i try to do this in a web app.

cheers

Comment: The error is saying your call lacks a scope. I'm guessing the scope is probably a delegated permission. In that case you cannot do the call with client credentials only, since it needs to be a *delegated call*. With a web application, you should be using Authorization Code grant instead of client credentials.

Comment: @juunas, you should add that as an answer, I would upvote it since what you are saying is correct :)

Comment: Added, problem probably is related to that but I couldn't test to make sure :)

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying your call lacks a scope. I'm guessing the scope is probably a delegated permission. In that case you cannot do the call with client credentials only, since it needs to be a *delegated call*. With a web application, you should be using Authorization Code grant instead of client credentials.

Answer (score 1):

We currently do not support authorization using ClientCredentials. You need to use user/password sign in so that the token will contain user specific information in order to be authorized on  the catalog.

_authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, clientId, new Uri(redirectUri), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always))

Hope this helps,
Monica

Answer (score 0):

> Application permission is based on client credentials. the delegate permission based on login user permission.

In this Data Catalog does't have any Application Permission. So, you Can't Access Without Login in window based application.

if you need without login popup you authContext.AcquireTokenAsync() method also the pass the username and password without prompt.

[image]

[image]

> So, you get  401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid
>   credentials.

because, the login token Does not contain any user specfic information and roles if you have a accesstoken just check in [jwt.io](http://jwt.io) website for insert you encoded token in left side right side show in that token information. it's contains some roles for access permission that permission does't contain your token so it's throw Unauthorized invalid credentials

i show example access token for below permission

[image]

Hopes it's Helpful for you